# Работа с MongoDB в Swift

Tags: swift, mongodb

Доброго времени суток. Только начал осваивать `Swift` (в `Xcode`) и столкнулся с "непониманием". Как работать с `MongoDB` в `Swift`? Находил различные библиотеки на гитхабе, но не смог разобраться как они подключаются к проекту. И есть ли способ работать с библиотеками как это делает `java&gradle`?

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендую написать простой `REST` сервис на `Java` или `Python` для доступа к данным `MongoDB`. 
Это гораздо проще, чем делать прямую связь со `Swift` и с архитектурной точки зрения намного правильнее.

Comment: Видимо это действительно "единственное" разумное решение. Пытался работать с Package Manager, но в итоге он вываливает кучу ошибок о не найденых библиотеках.

`Compile Swift Module 'BinaryJSON' (9 sources)
/Users/alekseyskynox/Downloads/test/Packages/CBSON-1.1.1/module.modulemap:2:12: error: header '/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0/bson.h' not found
    header "/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0/bson.h"`

Пытался ставить все по инструкции, но в итоге все равно валятся такого роди ошибки. Видимо Swift еще не готов для таких проектов, либо мои знания не тянут :)

Comment: Правильно ли я понял - Swift не приспособлен для разработки серверной части?

Comment: Да, к сожалению пока так и есть. Я не встречал адекватных библиотек для прямой работы с MongoDB и MySQL.